# JMeter: How to use Regular Expression to extract the value of a duplicate field?

Tags: regex, json, jmeter

I have the following Response Body JSON:

```
{
    "address": [
    {
        "id": "1234"
    }
    ],
    "id": "d1a4f010-48d9-434b-9b3a-2d2b12f5e38c"
}
```

I am trying to extract the value of the the *second* "id" field, i.e.

```
"id": "d1a4f010-48d9-434b-9b3a-2d2b12f5e38c"
```

I use this Regular Expression in JMeter:
**Regular Expression: "id":"(.+?)"**

When I run my test, it returns "1234" instead of the guid. How can I change my Regular Expression so that it returns the guid?

Comment: Are you using regex extractor?

Comment: You can use either Regex or Json Extractor: https://octoperf.com/blog/2017/09/07/jmeter-regular-expression-extractor/ or https://octoperf.com/blog/2017/03/09/how-to-extract-data-from-json-response-using-jmeter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lazy regex to find the guid directly instead of finding "id"

Something like this: `([0-9a-z-]{36}).*?`

If you are not sure how to create the regex, just use an online regex maker.

Answer (score 10):

Using **JMeter**, you can use [**Regular Expression Extractor**](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) ...

```
Reference Name: myid
Regular Expression: "id": "(.+?)"
Template: $1$
Match No.: 2
```

If you specify using a `Match No:`...

```
0 = Random Match
1 = First Match 
2 = Second Match
etc....
```

Or use corresponding variable to access the match. `${myid_2}`

The variables are set as follows:

```
myid_matchNr - Number of matches found, possibly 0
myid_n       - (n = 1, 2, etc..) Generated by the template
myid_n_gm    - (m = 0, 1, 2) Groups for the match (n) 
myid         - By itself it is always set to the default value
myid_gn      - Not set at all
```

Or judging by this case, if you prefer just regex and your strings are exactly as stated. You could do..

```
],\s+"id": "(.+?)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know jmeter but to get the value of second id this expression

```
 "id"\s*:.+?"id"\s*:\s*"([^"]*)"
```

It will return what you want on the $1 variable in a some languages. I suppose in jmeter you can have something similar to this in order to get the first group.

Maybe ${MYREF_g1} according [this page](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

The given response values

```
{
    "address": [
    {
        "id": "1234"
    }
    ],
    "id": "d1a4f010-48d9-434b-9b3a-2d2b12f5e38c"
}
```

Regular Expression to extract the second id values

Regular Expression formats

```
],\s\s\s\s\s"id": "(.+)"
```

Note

```
The above regex extract the following id values
d1a4f010-48d9-434b-9b3a-2d2b12f5e38c
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this:

```
"id":\s*"([0-9a-f\-]*)"
```

Answer (score 0):

try with below expression

```
"id": "([0-9a-z-])*+"
```

Answer (score -1):

step 1:

id:"1234";

id:(.+?)

"1234"

But we need only the value. So try this,

Step 2:

id:"1234";

id:('(.+?)')

1234