# JMeter regex vs regex tester

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have a piece of regex which works perfectly in regex101.com. However when I use it in JMeter it returns a different result.

```
assetName">My Asset Name</span>
```

Regex I am using:

```
assetName">([^"]+)<\/span>
```

regex101 returns what I am after:

```
My Asset Name
```

JMeter returns:

```
assetName">My Asset Name</span>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499737/jmeter-how-to-use-regular-expression-to-extract-the-value-of-a-duplicate-field/18501330#18501330

Comment: Can you show your JMeter code? It seems you're not extracting the matching group but the whole result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is correct.

You might have left `Match No` field blank. Enter 1.

regarding `Match No` - check  [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)  for more details.

Ex:  `${ASSET}` returns `My Asset Name`.

[image]