# Regex to get a field of Json

Tags: json, regex

I have a JSON text which is returned by an API. I need to grab the value of "id" field so I can use it in a test (I am doing a corrolate test in JMeter).

I can try and find the "id":  text however I cannot get the Z3G2D93 part.

**Regex:**

/"id":"(.+?)"/g

**JSON :**

```
{  
   "req":{  
      "dat":{  
         "bt":"",
         "ot":"07-Apr 08:21",
         "typ":"PickUp",
         "tot":"3480",
         "ast":"",
         "an":"Test Test",
         "id":"Z3G2D93"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: To expand on @torazaburo: if you have JSON, then the tool to use is a JSON parser. Using regexp for JSON data extraction is like using Swiss Army knife to eat pasta, when forks are readily available.

Comment: Your regex looks OK. What do you get with it?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: this may be helpful :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499737/jmeter-how-to-use-regular-expression-to-extract-the-value-of-a-duplicate-field

see the answer by user `hwnd`

Comment: Thanks guys. This was being written in JMeter (not in a programming language).  My regex returns the "id" as well (and not just the value of id) however I worked around it by replacing part of the second JSON message (in a correlated test) with what was returned by this regex and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure Regular Expression Extractor as follows:

- Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `id`
- Regular Expression: `"id":"(.+?)"`
- Template: `$1$`

By the way, you can test your Regular Expressions in JMeter right in [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener using RegExp Tester mode like:

[image: RegExp Tester]

See [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for more information on how to get to the bottom of JMeter script failure.

By the way, it might be easier to deal with JSON responses using [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/)